# How to compare and substitute strings in different lines in unix

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed

I want to compare and substitute strings present in different lines in unix

For example I have a file with two words in each line

```
<a> <b>
<d> <e>
<b> <c>
<c> <e>
```

If second word of any line matched with first word of any other line then second word of this line should be replaced with second word of matched line and it should iterate until there is no match between second word of the line with first word of another line

I need result like

```
<a> <e>
<b> <e>
<c> <e>
<d> <e>
```

I am new to unix and not getting any idea how to implement this. Can any one give suggestions or explain how we can do this

Comment: by "and it should iterate until there is no match ..." do you mean it should compare line 1 with line 3, and then line 4 and so on?

Comment: Yes. you are right Ashkan! It should search for match in all lines.

Comment: with this as input `<a> <b>` first line, `<e> <z>` second line and `<b> <e>` third line what is your desired output?

Comment: desires output will be <a> <e>
    <e> <z>
    <b> <e>

Comment: now second word of first line and first word of second line are equal, shouldn't it be replaced with <z>? i.e to become <a> <z> <e> <z> <b> <e> or there are some other conditions?

Comment: It should be <a> <z>
<b> <z>
<e> <z> . Sorry Ashkan!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is VERY clearly a case for a recursive descent solution:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function descend(node) {return (map[node] in map ? descend(map[node]) : map[node])}
{ map[$1] = $2 }
END { for (key in map) print key, descend(key) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<a> <e>
<b> <e>
<c> <e>
<d> <e>
```

If infinite recursion in your input is a possibility, here;s an approach that will print as the 2nd field the last node before the recursion starts and put a "*" next to it so you know it's happening:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function descend(node,  child, descendant) {
    stack[node]
    child = map[node]
    if (child in map) {
        if (child in stack) {
            descendant = node "*"
        }
        else {
            descendant = descend(child)
        }
    }
    else {
        descendant = child
    }
    delete stack[node]
    return descendant
}
{ map[$1] = $2 }
END { for (key in map) print key, descend(key) }
```

.

```
$ cat file
<w> <w>
<x> <y>
<y> <z>
<z> <x>
<a> <b>
<d> <e>
<b> <c>
<c> <e>

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<w> <w>*
<x> <z>*
<y> <x>*
<z> <y>*
<a> <e>
<b> <e>
<c> <e>
<d> <e>
```

If you need the output order to match the input order and/or or to print duplicate lines twice, change the bottom 2 lines of the script to:

```
{ keys[++numKeys] = $1; map[$1] = $2 }
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        print key, descend(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: _"This is VERY clearly a case for a recursive descent solution"_ I think I am agree with that but I've got Segmentation fault with <a> <b>
<e> <z>
<b> <b> as input

Comment: @Ed Morton it seems intresting. Can you please explain a bit or suggest any references

Comment: @Ashkan - yes, given infinitely recursive input the solution will infinitely recurse. If that can happen the OP needs to update his sample input and describe how he wants it handled (e.g. stop after N iterations or stop when the current node is already on the stack). Until then it's reasonable to assume that since the OP didn't show it as a possible input, it can't happen.

Comment: @shalini google "recursive descent algorithm" and you'll find a ton of descriptions. The function `descend()` just calls itself until it hits the bottom of the sequence of mappings stored in the array `map[]` and then returns whatever that bottom value was. So given `map[a]=b, map[b]=c, and map[c]=e` as built from your input file, `descend(a)` will call `descend(b)` which will call `descend(c)` which will return `e` and that return code will get passed all the way back up the stack of function calls so at the top level `descend(a)` returns `e`.

Comment: @Ashkan I just added a version of `descend()` that shows one approach to handling infinite recursion in the inputa in case anyone's interested. I added some local variables and changed the ternary expression to if-elses to make it a bit clearer what the function does.

Comment: @Ed Morton, +1, My my answer will be in an infinite loop in these situation and I was wondering how to solve that. One other improvement to this would be handling repeated lines if it can happen in OP's input.

Comment: @Ashkan right now it handles repeated lines by ignoring them, I just added an alternative to the end of my answer that would print them. As for duplicate `$1`s - just reporting and skipping them if `$1 in map` would work. We'd need some input from the OP on desired behavior in those cases.

Comment: This one is a keeper! Bookmarked. Thanks @EdMorton!

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my (@buff);
sub output {
    my $last = pop @buff;
    print map "$_ $last\n", @buff;
    @buff = ();
}

while (<>) {
    my @F = split;
    output() if @buff and $F[0] ne $buff[-1]; # End of a group.
    push @buff, $F[0] unless @buff;           # Start a new group.
    push @buff, $F[1];
}

output();                                     # Don't forget to print the last buffer.
```

Explanation: Read the input line by line. Keep a list of words to be printed with the same second word. If the first word is different than the second word of the previous line, print the buffered output.

Comment: Hi Choroba ..Thanks for the code and explanation!! does it compares only with previous line (the first word is different than the second word of the previous line). It would be nice if it compares all lines. How can I do this. I have no idea of perl

Comment: @shalini: Try it. Save it to a file `compare.pl`, run `perl compare.pl input` and see.

Comment: Hi Choroba Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your code. it didnt worked for <a> <b>
<c> <d>
<b> <d>. It is giving the same output!

Comment: @shalini: What output would you expect?

Comment: @choroba +1 for my blatant copy of logic `;)`

Comment: @shalini based on your description, is that supposed to give same output. `If second word of the line1 matched with first word of line2 then second word of line1 should be replaced with second word of line2 and it should iterate until there is no match between second word of the line1 with first word of line2`. Please update your question to show what you really need.

Comment: @choroba <a> <d>
<c> <d>
<b> <d>. The result should not have a match of second word of a line and first word of another line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{i++;a[i]=$1;b[i]=$2;next}
      END{
            for(i=1;i in a;i++)
            {
              f=1;
              while (f==1)
              {
                f=0;
                for(j=i+1;j in a;j++)
                {
                  if(b[i]==a[j])
                  {
                    b[i]=b[j];
                    f=1;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            for(i=1;i in a;i++)
            {
              print a[i],b[i];
            }
          }' input.txt
```

Input:

```
<a> <b>
<d> <e>
<b> <c>
<c> <e>
```

Output:

```
<a> <e>
<d> <e>
<b> <e>
<c> <e>
```

Input:

```
<a> <b>
<e> <z>
<b> <e>
```

Output:

```
<a> <z>
<e> <z>
<b> <e>
```

---

**EDIT**

If you need to get

```
<a> <z>
<e> <z>
<b> <z>
```

As output from the second input you can change this line:

```
if(b[i]==a[j])
```

to:

```
if(j!=i&&b[i]==a[j])
```

and this:

```
for(j=i+1;j in a;j++)
```

to:

```
for(j=1;j in a;j++)
```

Also note that this code assumes there is not a case where second word of a line is equal to both first word of a line and its second word i.e:

```
<a> <b>
<e> <z>
<b> <b>
```

In that case the execution of the code will never ends.

Comment: @Thanks a lot for your time Ashkan. Last change gave me the correct results.