# Graph traversal using awk

Tags: shell, awk, graph-theory, text-processing

Considering the following file representing a cyclic graph, I am looking for a shell script to find the all reachable nodes beginning from any node in the graph?

A.txt (first element of each row is the node and the rest are reachable adjacent nodes from it):

```
a3 a4
a2 a4 a5
a4 a5
a5 a6
a6 a7
a7 a8
a8 a9
a9
```

Desired output files (B.txt and C.txt) must be the output of either DFS or BFS and include the depth (distance) from any beginning node to its reachable nodes. Something like:

B.txt

```
a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a2 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a6 a7 a8 a9
a7 a8 a9
a8 a9
a9
```

C.txt

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

Awk is preferred, though any kind of shell scripting is OK.

Comment: Some things are not clear here. Based on your reachability output, it is obvious that the graph is directed: a8 reaches a9, but a9 does not reach a8.  Secondly, for some reason, every node reaches itself. Thirdly, this is the only sense in which the example graph is "cyclic". In other regards it is acyclic: each vertex An has only higher-numbered vertices Am adjacent to where m > n. there is no backreference (except implicitly from An to An).

Comment: The Perl solution assumes that the graph is acyclic, and that for any m > n, node Am is reachable from An, and other nodes are not reachable.  Thus, the nodes can be ordered into a sequence, and we just have to extract suffixes of that sequence.   This is not a proper depth-first search starting at any arbitrary point in a graph (even in a DAG).  Consider a graph like (a1 a2) (a1 a3)  (a3 a4) (a3 a5)  (a2 a6) (a2 a7): a balanced binary tree.  Starting at node a3, we reach only a4 and a5.  From a2, we reach only a6 and a7: different subsets of nodes that are not suffixes of a common sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085230/1745001, here's an awk solution:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function calcMinDepth(parent,  childArray, childNr, child) {
    ++depth
    split(children[parent],childArray)
    for (childNr=1; childNr in childArray; childNr++) {
        child = childArray[childNr]
        if ( (minDepth[origin,child] > depth) ||
                (minDepth[origin,child] == 0) ) {
            minDepth[origin,child] = depth
            calcMinDepth(child)
        }
    }
    --depth
    return
}

function prtInfo(parent,  childArray, childNr, child) {
    split(children[parent],childArray)
    for (childNr=1; childNr in childArray; childNr++) {
        child = childArray[childNr]
        if (!seen[child]++) {
            printf " %s", child > "B.txt"
            printf " %d", minDepth[origin,child] > "C.txt"
            prtInfo(child)
        }
    }
    return
}

{
    parents[++numParents] = $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        children[$1] = (i>2 ? children[$1] FS : "") $i
    }
}

END {
    for (parentNr=1; parentNr<=numParents; parentNr++) {
        origin = parents[parentNr]
        calcMinDepth(origin)
    }

    for (parentNr=1; parentNr<=numParents; parentNr++) {
        origin = parents[parentNr]
        printf "%s", origin > "B.txt"
        printf "%d", depth  > "C.txt"
        prtInfo(origin)
        print "" > "B.txt"
        print "" > "C.txt"
        delete seen     # or split("",seen) for non-gawk
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file

$ cat B.txt
a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a2 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a6 a7 a8 a9
a7 a8 a9
a8 a9
a9

$ cat C.txt
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. If you can use `perl` then here is one way of doing it:

```
perl -lane '
    $seen{$F[0]}++ or push @seq, $F[0];
    push @rec, [ split ]; 
}{ 
   @seq = sort @seq;
   for my $ref (@rec) {
       my ($idx) = grep { $seq[$_] eq $ref->[-1] } 0..$#seq;
       print join " ", @$ref, @seq[$idx+1..$#seq] ;
   }
' file
a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a2 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a5 a6 a7 a8 a9
a6 a7 a8 a9
a7 a8 a9
a8 a9
a9
```

What we are doing here is splitting the line on whitespace. We create a hash `%seen` which looks for duplicate values and filters them from pushing to an array called `@seq`. Idea here is to build a unique list of sequences.

We split each line and push it an array called `@rec`. In the `END` block denoted by `}{`, we sort our sequences. For every array element, we first find the index of the last element of our line in our array of sequences. Idea is to print everything that follows that. Once we have the index, we print your output.

You can redirect the output to another file.

I am not sure about your last output. If you can add more details about it then I can try and come up with something.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I myself will try to write its equivalent awk version.

Comment: Sure. However, it will take me a while to write it as I just started writing scripts.