# Recursive key value in a file

Tags: python, bash, awk, grep

There is a file having two colums [can be understood as key and value] :

```
k1 v1
k2 v2
k3 v3
k4 k1
k5 k4
```

Now i want output like this from this file :

```
k1 v1
k2 v2
k3 v3
k4 k1 v1
k5 k4 k1 v1
```

For if some key's value is another key then apeend that value to that row. How could this be approached

THere could be multivalue keys as well k1 v1 and k1 x1. for multivalued keys, would like to have a new line with both the values :

```
k1 v1
k1 x1
k2 k1
```

Changes to

```
k1 v1
k1 x1
k2 k1 v1
k2 k1 x1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python code：

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dict = {}
fp = open('test.txt')
for line in fp.readlines():
    line = line.split(" ")
    dict[line[0]] = line[1].replace('\n','')
fp.close() 
dict = OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
for key in dict:
    if dict.has_key(dict[key]):
        print key,dict[key],dict[dict[key]]
    else:
        print key,dict[key]
```

source file：

```
k1 v1
k2 v2
k3 v3
k4 k1
k5 k4
k6 k2
k7 v8
```

result：

```
k1 v1
k2 v2
k3 v3
k4 k1 v1
k5 k4 k1
k6 k2 v2
k7 v8
```

Comment: If there are multiple entries for one key, k1 v1 and k1 x1. It will pick first entry. Can we somehow make it pick both and add a new line : k4 k1 v1 and k4 k1 x1

Comment: Shouldn't output line `k5 k4 k1` be `k5 k4 k1 v1` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Just tweak this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085230/1745001

to print every node in the descent instead of just the root and leaf nodes. For example, this will handle potential infinite recursion such as would occur if your input file contained both `k1 k2` and `k2 k1` and will print the output in the order the keys appear in the input file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function descend(node,  child, descendants) {
    stack[node]
    child = map[node]
    if (child in map) {
        if (child in stack) {
            descendants = node "*"
        }
        else {
            descendants = child " " descend(child)
        }
    }
    else {
        descendants = child
    }
    delete stack[node]
    return descendants
}
{ keys[++numKeys] = $1; map[$1] = $2 }
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        print key, descend(key)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
k1 v1
k2 v2
k3 v3
k4 k1 v1
k5 k4 k1 v1
```

Wrt the 2nd part of your question about handling both `k1 v1` and `k1 x1` - just tweak the above to use a 2D array or an array with a string of space-separated key values or similar instead of the 1D `map` array above, something like:

```
{
    if (!seen[$1]++) {
        keys[++numKeys] = $1
    }
    map[$1,++cnt[$1]] = $2
}
```

and modify the descend() function to loop on the contents of map[]

```
for (i=1; i<=cnt[node]; i++) {
    child = map[node,i]
    if (child in map) {
        ...
    }
}
```

instead of the current simple assignment it does:

```
child = map[node]
if (child in map) {
    ...
}
```

That may not be perfect as it's untested but it's the right idea and will be close and shouldn't be too hard for you to debug (i.e. I'm not going to!).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$  awk '($2 in hash){hash[$1]=$2" "hash[$2]; next} {hash[$1]=$2} END{for (i in hash) print i, hash[i]}' input
k1 v1
k2 v2
k3 v3
k4 k1 v1
k5 k4 k1 v1
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer addresses the first version of this question for which keys were single-valued.*

```
$ awk '{d[$1]=$2" "d[$2]; print $1,d[$1]}' file
k1 v1 
k2 v2 
k3 v3 
k4 k1 v1 
k5 k4 k1 v1
```

#### How it works

- `d[$1]=$2" "d[$2]`

  For every line, an item is added to the dictionary.  The key is given the first column.  The value is given by the second column and, separated by a space, any entry in the dictionary corresponding to the second column.
- `print $1,d[$1]`

  For every line, the first column and the corresponding dictionary value are printed.

#### Comments

This prints out the results for each line as it is encountered.  This guarantees that keys are output in the same order as the input file.

This approach prints an extra space at the end of each line.  If this is an issue, it could be easily very removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict={}
x1=fileobject.read()
for line in x1.splitlines():
    if line.split()[1] in dict.keys():
        dict[line.split()[0]]=line.split()[1]+" "+dict[line.split()[1]]
    else:
        dict[line.split()[0]]=line.split()[1]

print dict
```

This way you can have a dictionary of object with keys as you want.

Output:`{'k3': 'v3', 'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'v1', 'k5': 'k4 k1 v1', 'k4': 'k1 v1'}`

Answer (score 0):

For your updated requirements

In Awk

```
awk '{for(i=(b[$2]>0);i<=b[$2];i++){c[$1" "++b[$1]]=$2" "c[$2" "i];print $1,c[$1" "b[$1]]}}' file
```

#### Example

`input`

```
k1 v1
k1 x1
k1 y1
k2 k1
k2 k4
k3 k2
```

`output`

```
k1 v1
k1 x1
k1 y1
k2 k1 v1
k2 k1 x1
k2 k1 y1
k2 k4
k3 k2 k1 v1
k3 k2 k1 x1
k3 k2 k1 y1
k3 k2 k4
```

Comment: Also it doesn't handle the scenario when key might be later, as in : k1 v1, v1 v2 : should change to k1 v1 v2; v1 v2

Comment: @NooB8374 I don't even know what you mean, are you adding even more requirements ?

Comment: Lets say order of keys changed, K3 K2, K2 K4, K2 K1, K1 y1, K1 x1, k1 v1.., Then this doesn't work..