# Awk scripting to obtain links for a chosen column 1 elements for an input file

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, grep

I have a data set as below:

```
2,5
159,5
2,100
2,858
3,100
3,114
3,171
3,858
5,100
858,2
2,2456
4500,2
2456,3
```

If I choose an element from column 1 such as 2. I need to get the corresponding elements of the chosen element from column 2.

I have used :

```
awk -F, '$1=="2" {print $2}' Sample.txt
```

This returns the corresponding column 2 elements of the element 2 which is as below:

```
5
100
858
2456
```

I would like the next iteration to perform a check on 5 and return the column 2 elements. In this case, 5 should return 100 but it is already shown by 2 so I don't need 100. The same check for 100 and so forth till 2456. For 2456 it should return 3 which is the corresponding column 2 element and is unique. I would want that iteration to continue the same for 3 and return the unique corresponding column 2 unique elements until there are no column 2 elements to return.

Final output should look like :

`5
100
858
2456
3
114
171`
 
`# 3 is got as a column 2 element of 2456 and 114,171 are got as column 2 element of 3. Since, 114 and 171 don't have any further unique column 2 elements (Refer the sample data set above). The iteration stops. Can this be recursively achieved as I am able to do it only for the first chosen element.`

Comment: What output do you want to see?

Comment: It sounds like you want some version of this recursive descent parser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25085230/1745001. If so and you can't figure out how to tweak it yourself to produce the output you want, edit your question to show that desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The command you have can be changed to:

```
awk -F, '$1==2 {print $2}' Sample.txt >> tmp.txt
5
100
858
2456
```

Comment: @JID It not, but it may help the OP  to understand `awk` and see how it can be used for his not easy to understand question.

Comment: @JID Thanks for optimising the instruction. As a first step I was hoping to do the same operation as shown by you on all the elements generated in the tmp.txt and write them in a single file. Like Instead of 2 take 5 and go on till  2456.

Comment: @SujayShalawadi Jotne not me :)