# How to count how many #ifdef clauses have at least an #elif but no #else in a set of C files?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, c-preprocessor

I have a bunch of C files and I need to count how many #ifdef clauses have an #elif clause but do not have an #else clause in those files, including possible nested #ifdef clauses. For instance, in the first code snippet there are no matches, while in the second code snippet, there are two matches:

## 1: No matches (the #ifdef contains an #else clause)

```
#ifdef A
...
#elif B
...
#else
...
#endif
```

## 2: Two matches (there are two #ifdef clauses with #elif clauses but without a corresponding #else)

```
#ifdef X1
...
#elif X2
...
#endif
...
#ifdef Y1
...
#elif Y2
...
#elif Y3
...
#endif
```

I'm looking for a way to do this using some command line tool, such as grep, awk or sed, but no luck so far. So, I'm still open for easier alternatives, if any.

I have tried this regular expression using grep: `'^(?=.*#elif)((?!#elif|#else).)(?=.*\#endif).)*$'` (an #elif that is not followed by another #elif or #else and have a corresponding #endif), but it does not work, since clauses are in different lines.

Comment: I just realized that my regular expression would also fail to match an #elif with a nested #ifdef containing an #elif or #else...

Comment: If I were writing this, I'd go with perl.

Comment: Note that you'll have problems because these constructs can be nested.  Presumably, `#ifdef X / #ifdef Y / #else / #endif / #elif defined Z / #endif` does match (once).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler unfortunately, I barely know perl...

Comment: what about a countable *ifdef* nested inside a *ifdef* inclunding an *else* ? Do we count the nested one and not the host one or count nothing ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Yes, I want to count the nested even though the host is not counted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a recursive-descent parser that descends every time it finds a "#ifdef" and returns every time it finds "#endif". See [How to compare and substitute strings in different lines in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082846/how-to-compare-and-substitute-strings-in-different-lines-in-unix/25085230#25085230) for an example of one written in awk.

You didn't provide useful sample input or expected output so I had to make up my own to test it (and so it might not be exactly what you need), but you will want something like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function descend(cond,    numElifs,numElses,gotEndif) {
    while ( !gotEndif && (getline > 0) ) {
        if      ( /#ifdef/ ) { descend($2) }
        else if ( /#elif/  ) { numElifs++  }
        else if ( /#else/  ) { numElses++  }
        else if ( /#endif/ ) { gotEndif++ }
    }
    print cond, numElses+0, numElifs+0, ((numElifs>0)&&(numElses==0) ? "UhOh" : "")
    return
}
/#ifdef/ { descend($2) }
```

.

```
$ cat file
#ifdef A
#elif B
#else
  #ifdef C
  #elif D
  #endif

  #ifdef E
  #elif F
  #else
  #endif

  #ifdef G
  #elif H
    #ifdef I
    #else
    #endif
  #elif J
  #endif
#endif
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
C 0 1 UhOh
E 1 1
I 1 0
G 0 2 UhOh
A 1 1
```

Note that this IS an appropriate use of getline but see http://awk.info/?tip/getline before using it elsewhere.

All the usual caveats about really needing a parser for the language (to handle e.g. #ifdef inside comments or string) instead of a script like this apply.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Apart from the assumptions that `#if`, `#ifdef`, etc. doesn't appear in string or comments, **and** that the code is written in a sane manner, i.e. no crazy stuffs like:

```
#i\
fdef
```

I made at least another assumption that `if`, `ifdef` must be immediately preceded by `#`, while there can be arbitrary tab or space characters in between.

The regex below has been tested to work for PCRE and Perl flavors.

```
# Look-ahead to allow overlapping matches
(?=
  (
    # Just define patterns. Doesn't match anything.
    (?(DEFINE)
      (?<re>
        # Match lines not ifdef, if, elif, else, endif macro
        (?![ \t]*  [#](?:if(?:def)?|elif|else|endif))  .*\R
        |
        # Recurse into another if or ifdef
        (?1)
      )
    )

    # Only match ifdef at top level, and allow if and ifdef nested
    ^[ \t]*  [#](?(R)if(?:def)?|ifdef)  .*\R
    (?&re)*

    # Match elif clause at least once at top level
    (?(R)  
      |
      (?:
        [ \t]*  [#]elif  .*\R
        (?&re)*
      )
    )

    # Match 0 or more elif clauses
    (?:
      [ \t]*  [#]elif  .*\R
      (?&re)*
    )*

    # Optional else clause nested
    # else clause not allowed at top level
    (?(R)
      (?:
        [ \t]*  [#]else.  *\R
        (?&re)*
      )?
    )

    # Match endif
    [ \t]*[#]endif.*\R?+

  )
)
```

Required flags: `m` (multiline, for the `^`), and `x` (free-spacing syntax and comment).

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/cV2jI9/10)

The construct `(?(R)...)` is a conditional construct, which tests if we are currently inside any routine call. It is used to check the current nesting level of `if`/`ifdef`.

Technically, `(?&re)` which calls into the pattern defined in `(?(DEFINE)...)` counts as routine call, but except for `(?1)` which enters into another nested `if`/`ifdef`, the first alternation only operates on lines without `if`/`ifdef`, so it doesn't affect the final result.

## Appendix

### General purpose version

This is the regex for general case, without the restrictions on `else` and `elif` clause as required in the question. It is simpler, since we don't have to take care of the restrictions.

If you have a hard time digesting the regex above, this could be a good starting point.

```
(?=
  (

    (?(DEFINE)
      (?<re>
        (?![ \t]*  [#](?:if(?:def)?|elif|else|endif))  .*\R
        |
        (?1)
      )
    )

    ^[ \t]*  [#]if(?:def)?  .*\R
    (?&re)*

    (?:
      [ \t]*  [#]elif  .*\R
      (?&re)*
    )*

    (?:
      [ \t]*  [#]else.  *\R
      (?&re)*
    )?

    [ \t]*[#]endif.*\R?+

  )
)
```

[**Demon on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/xG9oU7/1)

### Test case

```
#ifdef X1

#elif X2

#endif



#ifdef Y1
#define DEF

  #if defined(X) && U == 0
  #elif
  #endif


#elif Y2

  #ifdef Y1
  #elif Y2
  #else
  #endif

#elif Y3

#endif



#ifdef X

  #ifdef Y
  #else

  #endif

  #ifdef K
  #elif

    #ifdef N1
    #elif
    #endif
    #ifdef N2
    #elif
    #endif

  #endif

#elif defined Z

  #ifdef T
  #elif
  #endif

#endif

#ifdef Y
  #ifdef E1
  #endif
  #ifdef E2
  #elif
  #endif
#endif


#ifdef Y
#elif
#endif
```

Comment: Although quite didactic, now I think that using such a RegEx might be overkill. But thanks for all your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count them this should work.
As far as my testing it should work fine with nesting.

```
awk '/#ifdef/{x++}
     /#elif/&&a[x]!="q"{a[x]="s"}
     /#else/{a[x]="q"}
     /#endif/{total+=a[x]=="s";delete a[x];x--}
     END{print total}' file
```

For EdMortons input file this would result in

```
2
```